# Woocomerce session cookie

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web creada en PHP y en un subdirectorio he instalado Wordpress con Woocommerce. Woocomerce utiliza para guardar la sesión wp_woocommerce_session. ¿Sabéis si se podría utilizar para todo el dominio, no solo para la parte de wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Para aquel que se encuentre con el mismo problema. Os dejo el código que debéis añadir al archivo wp-config para tener las cookies de Wordpress disponibles en todo el dominio.

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Yo lo he añadido debajo de la línea:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```